# Raspberry Pi Sample App - Data Collection with Cassandra using DTH11 sensor

Tags: raspberry-pi, sensors, kaa

Running the sample for the raspberry pi with cassandra data collection from the kaa sandbox.

Runs without an issue. But while querying the data using the following commands

```
$ cqlsh
$ use kaa;
```

AND

To see data stored in sensor_per_row table, use select statement:

```
$ SELECT * FROM sensor_per_row;
```

**I get back only the structure of the table with column names. No data is returned.**

What am I possibly doing wrong? the below is one way messing the stuff, the **"Host"** and **"Port"** . I didn't change anything yet, just running the sample app, not getting the data back. If this is solved I can move further.

Any help is appreciated. Below is a snapshot of the default configuration and the sandbox terminal
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you follow the instructions for Cassandra data analytics demo from Sandbox, it should work correctly.
The "**Host**" and "**Port**" in Cassandra nodes log appender configuration section for Sandbox should be "**localhost**" and "**9042**" accordingly. It describes the list of Cassandra hosts.
If you don't have any issues after running application and see for example:

```
Data collection demo started
Going to add 1th log record: { id: 'Sensor 1', region: 'Region 1', model: 'DHT11', val: 25 }
...
```

Please investigate logs of kaa-node service (or add kaa-node.log file here), for details refer to our [Troubleshooting guide](http://docs.kaaproject.org/display/KAA/Troubleshooting+guide).